# Is there a way to click on coordinates in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am attempting to create an auto-clicker application and was curious if there is any actual way to click with just x and y cords, and if so can I do it outside of the window? I am using C# UWP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP: Simulate click at specific coordinates on Windows IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469382/uwp-simulate-click-at-specific-coordinates-on-windows-iot)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't. I can't see any place where it talks about condiments.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to simulate a mouse click by using APIs under [Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection?view=winrt-19041) namespace.  And you could inject a mouse click outside of the window by this way. More information about simulating user input through input injection, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/input-injection). Note to add the [inputInjectionBrokered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/input-injection#setup) capability.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
    var infoPosition = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();
    infoPosition.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.Absolute;
    infoPosition.DeltaX = 50;
    infoPosition.DeltaY = 50;

    var infoDown = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();
    infoDown.DeltaX = 50;
    infoDown.DeltaY = 50;
    infoDown.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftDown;

    var infoUp = new InjectedInputMouseInfo();
    infoUp.DeltaX = 0;
    infoUp.DeltaY = 0;
    infoUp.MouseOptions = InjectedInputMouseOptions.LeftUp;

    inputInjector.InjectMouseInput(new[] { infoPosition,infoDown, infoUp });
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        inputInjector.InjectMouseInput(new[] { infoPosition, infoDown, infoUp });

    }

}
```

Note that values of `DeltaX` property and `DeltaY` property are relative to the last mouse wheel event, you need to set `MouseOptions` property as [InjectedInputMouseOptions.Absolute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputmouseoptions?view=winrt-19041) to indicate the coordinates is an absolute value.

Comment: So, does this move to the absolute location (50,50) and then lefts click with a delta of (50,50), i.e. the click is at (100,100)?
Why is there a loop doing this injection 10 times? I saw that elsewhere but can't see why it's desirable.